# Fixing Wifi dropout on a raspberry-pi

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am new to raspberry pi, and not very comfortable with linux. I am facing issues with WIFI dropouts and searching led me to this article: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/test-and-configure#fixing-wifi-dropout-issues, it states that I have to create a file called 8192cu.conf. From reading this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=44044, I understand that 8192 is a realtek device, which suggests that the advice in the first article will work with this realtek device. I got my pi as a kit online, and I do not think the wifi adapter dongle is realtek. Typing `lsmod` is giving me this:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
fuse                   78200  3 
snd_bcm2835            19584  0 
arc4                    1684  2 
snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s     6202  0 
regmap_mmio             2818  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
snd_soc_core          127841  1 snd_soc_bcm2708_i2s
snd_compress            8259  1 snd_soc_core
regmap_i2c              1661  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine       5505  1 snd_soc_core
regmap_spi              1913  1 snd_soc_core
joydev                  9257  0 
snd_pcm                83845  3 snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_page_alloc          5132  1 snd_pcm
evdev                  10661  4 
snd_seq                55484  0 
snd_seq_device          6469  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              20998  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
leds_gpio               2079  0 
rt2800usb              17425  0 
rt2800lib              80336  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00usb              11661  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              44907  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
led_class               4118  2 leds_gpio,rt2x00lib
snd                    62252  7 snd_bcm2835,snd_soc_core,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
mac80211              329911  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
cfg80211              212241  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
sg                     19877  0 
crc_ccitt               1541  1 rt2800lib
rfkill                 19784  2 cfg80211
```

I guess cfg80211, mac80211 and rfkill have something to do with wifi. But I do not know what should be the name of the file that I should create to avoid wifi dropouts? or how I can solve the dropouts.

Comment: What kind of power supply you have? I'm asking, because I had problems with Realtek 8188 Wifi and low quality 1A power supply. 2A power supply fixed it.

Comment: It is a 2A power supply.

Comment: I think you could get better/faster help on [Raspberry Pi community](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com) or [Unix & Linux community](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could not find the problem, or the solution, but on some forum found a workaround. The below is the code, modified to log out events and work as a simple cron job. (credits to original code author to be given once I find that post again.)

```
#!/bin/sh

   echo "---------- START ----------" >> /home/pi/wifiScriptRunLog.txt
   date >> /home/pi/wifiScriptRunLog.txt
   if ifconfig wlan0 | grep -q "inet addr:" ; then
      echo "Network connection up." >> /home/pi/wifiScriptRunLog.txt
   else
      echo "Network connection down! Attempting reconnection." >> /home/pi/wifiScriptRunLog.txt
      sudo ifdown --force wlan0
      sudo ifup --force wlan0
   fi
   echo "------------ END -----------" >> /home/pi/wifiScriptRunLog.txt
```

Save this as a file (without extension), place in /etc/cron.hourly folder and make executable.